# What is the best way to pass a default/initial value to a Jetpack Compose TextField?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-livedata, hoisting

**Context**

I'm trying to figure out how to pass default values to TextField Composables. I have seen a few solutions out there, but I'm looking at some feedback on what is the most widely accepted solution.

**Example**

Let's say you have a `ViewModel` like this:

```
class UserProfileViewModel : ViewModel() {
    sealed class State {
        data class UserDataFetched(
            val firstName: String
            // ...
        ) : State()
        object ErrorFetchingData: State()
        object ErrorUpdatingData: State()
        object Loading: State()
        // ...
    }

    val state = MutableLiveData<State>()
    // ...
}
```

This `ViewModel` is for a piece of UI that – let's say, lets you update the user name through an `TextField` – looks like this:

```
val state by viewModel.state.observeAsState(initial = UserProfileViewModel.State.Loading)
MaterialTheme() {
    UserProfileScreen(
        state = state
    )
}
```

```
@Composable
fun UserProfileScreen(
    state: UserProfileViewModel.State,
) {
    val userNameValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }
    Column {
        TextField(
            value = userNameValue.value,
            onValueChange = {
                userNameValue.value = it
            }
        )
        //...
    }
}
```

Now, when I get a `State.UserDataFetched` event the first time this screen is prompted to the user, I want to pre-fill the `TextField` with the `firstName` I got in there.

I have seen a few solutions out there, but I'm not sure which one is most widely-accepted or why.

**#1 Use a flag variable**

```
@Composable
fun UserProfileScreen(
    state: UserProfileViewModel.State,
) {
    val userHasModifiedText = remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    val userNameValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue()) }

    if (state is UserProfileViewModel.State.UserDataFetched) {
        if (!userHasModifiedText.value) {
            userNameValue.value = TextFieldValue(state.firstName)
        }
    }
    Column {
        TextField(
            value = userNameValue.value,
            onValueChange = {
                userNameValue.value = it
                userHasModifiedText.value = true
            }
        )
        //...
    }
}
```

The idea would be to use `userHasModifiedText` to keep track of wether the user has typed anything in the `TextField` or not – that way we avoid changing the value upon recomposition.

**#2 Use derivedStateOf**

```
@Composable
fun UserProfileScreen(
    state: UserProfileViewModel.State,
    defaultFirstName: String? = null,
) {
    val userNameString = remember { mutableStateOf<String?>(null) }
    val userNameValue = remember {
        derivedStateOf {
            if (userNameString.value != null)
                TextFieldValue(userNameString.value ?: "")
            else
                TextFieldValue(defaultFirstName ?: "")
        }
    }

    Column {
        TextField(
            value = userNameValue,
            onValueChange = {
                userNameString.value = it
            }
        )
        //...
    }
}
```

Taken from this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74632382/1403997).

**#3 use LaunchedEffect**

```
@Composable
fun UserProfileScreen(
    state: UserProfileViewModel.State
) {
    val userNameValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue) }
    LaunchedEffect(true) {
        if (state is UserProfileViewModel.State.UserDataFetched) {
            userNameValue.value = TextFieldValue(state.firstName)
        }
    }

    Column {
        TextField(
            value = userNameValue.value,
            onValueChange = {
                userNameValue.value = it
            }
        )
        //...
    }
}
```

**#4 have a specific LiveData property**

Let's say that instead of using that `sealed class` we keep track of what that field through a `LiveData` property

```
class UserProfileViewModel : ViewModel() {
    // ...
    val firstName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    // ...
}
```

then we would do something like

```
val firstName by viewModel.firstName.observeAsState("")
MaterialTheme() {
    UserProfileScreen(
        firstName = firstName,
        onFirstNameEditTextChanged = {
            viewModel.firstName.value = it
        }
    )
}
```

```
@Composable
fun UserProfileScreen(
    firstName: String,
    onFirstNameEditTextChanged: ((String) -> Unit) = {}
) {
    val userNameValue = remember { mutableStateOf(TextFieldValue) }
    Column {
        TextField(
            value = userNameValue.value,
            onValueChange = {
                userNameValue.value = it
                onFirstNameEditTextChanged(it.text)
            }
        )
        //...
    }
}
```

**Notes**

- I'm using `LiveData` because that's what the project is using right now. Switching over to `State` or Kotlin `Flow` isn't something we have in the roadmap.

**Edit #1**

Since this question has been flagged as opinionated, let me be completely clear about what I am looking to get out of it.

I have listed all the solutions I have been able to find as to how to set an initial/default value on a TextField. If there is a better solution or a solution that I haven't listed here that addresses this issue better, please feel free to share it and explain why it is better.

I don't think an answer like "just pass the ViewModel" addresses the issue wholly. What if I'm using this composable on a Fragment and my ViewModel is scoped to the entire Activity? If I dismiss the Fragment I don't want the TextField value to be remembered through the ViewModel. I'm also looking for something simple, as far as I understand if the Composables are self-contained, that's better, so I'm not sure that tying a Composable to a ViewModel is the best solution.

I'm looking for a clear, concise solution that is widely accepted in the Android community so my team and I can adopt it.

My expectation is that you open the screen, we fetch a value for the default name from somewhere, we pre-fill that on the TextField and that's it. If the user deletes the whole text, that's it. If the user dismisses the screen and comes back, then we fetch again the value and pre-fill it again. **If the goal of this question is still unclear or you think it might be up to discussion, let me know, and I'll try to clarify further.**

Comment: I think you should go with livedata.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,

```
class UserProfileViewModel : ViewModel() {
    sealed class State {
```

You don't really want to have a ViewModel like this. Because it doesn't get a reference to SavedStateHandle. If your ViewModel doesn't get a SavedStateHandle, you should already be suspicious for the rest of your code -- if there is user input on the screen but no SavedStateHandle (and you don't deliberately invalidate the session after process death manually) then you will just lose user input.

Next, TextField requires you to make the current text ***synchronously** available, so the evaluated text that is inputted into the TextField should be either `MutableLiveData<String>` managed with `setValue()` or it can also be `MutableState<String>` (the Google recommendation) but it also works with `MutableStateFlow<>` + `collectLatest {}` as long as there is no `flowOn()` or `delay()` etc. and everything happens on **Dispatchers.Main.immediate** (NOT `Dispatchers.Main`).

Once you consider the separation of "State" so that your TextField will behave as intended, you will have

```
class UserProfileViewModel(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    val firstName by savedStateHandle.saveable { mutableStateOf<String>("") 
    val didFetchUserData by savedStateHandle.saveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    val hadErrorSavingData by mutableStateOf(false) // unlikely that this needs state restoration
    val hadErrorUpdatingData by mutableStateOf(false) // unlikely that this needs state restoration
}

// "LOADING" state is just `didFetchData == false`.

// You might say "but I want a `State` class that presents this" 
// but then you won't be able to guarantee that the TextField values update
// immediately, and you will break your code.
```

I guess you can do `viewModel.isLoading` and `val isLoading get() = !didFetchUserData` if you really need that property explicit.

Once you've destructured this `State` class you originally had, then you realize this is actually either terrible for recomposition (all reads should be deferred if possible); so **then** you create a `@Stable` state holder that serves as a lazy accessor for state properties that wraps the state access with deferred reads/writes, but any updates should still reflect on it. This way, you do end up "duplicating your state holder" (ViewModel <-> State), but at least you also separate it from `ViewModel()` (Android-bound class that cannot be preview'd).

So you end up with

```
class UserProfileViewModel(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    private var firstName by savedStateHandle.saveable { mutableStateOf("") }

    // ...
    private val didFetchUserData by savedStateHandle.saveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    private val hadErrorSavingData by mutableStateOf(false) // unlikely that this needs state restoration
    private val hadErrorUpdatingData by mutableStateOf(false) // unlikely that this needs state restoration

    val state = UserProfileState(
        firstNameProvider = { firstName },
        // ...
        didFetchUserDataProvider = { didFetchUserData },
        hadErrorSavingDataProvider = { hadErrorSavingData },
        hadErrorUpdatingDataProvider = { hadErrorUpdatingData },
        onUpdateFirstName = { firstName = it },
    )
}

@Stable
class UserProfileState(
    private val firstNameProvider: () -> String,
    private val didFetchUserDataProvider: () -> Boolean,
    private val hadErrorSavingDataProvider: () -> Boolean,
    private val hadErrorUpdatingDataProvider: () -> Boolean,
    private val onUpdateFirstName: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    val firstName: String get() = firstNameProvider()
    private val didFetchUserData: Boolean get() = didFetchUserDataProvider()
    val hadErrorSavingData: Boolean get() = hadErrorSavingDataProvider()
    val hadErrorUpdatingData: Boolean get() = hadErrorUpdatingDataProvider()

    fun updateFirstName(firstName: String) {
        onUpdateFirstName(firstName)
    }

    val isLoading: Boolean get() = !didFetchUserData
}
```

Then you should be able to do

```
@Composable
fun NavigationGraph() {
    ...
    val userProfileViewModel = viewModel<UserProfileViewModel>()
    UserProfileScreen(
        state = userProfileViewModel.state
    )
}

@Composable
fun UserProfileScreen(
    state: UserProfileState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .then(modifier)
    ) {
        if (state.isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier
                .size(48.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center))
        } else {
            TextField(
                value = state.firstName,
                onValueChange = state::updateFirstName,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

But if you use LiveData, then the solution should be similar, but not entirely the same. All calls to `savedStateHandle.saveable { mutableStateOf("")`  is `savedStateHandle.getLiveData("key", "")` (default value).

The real problem is that LiveData by default doesn't notify Compose, so you actually need to use `observeAsState()` in your Composable, and THEN create the `State` class from there.

```
class UserProfileViewModel(savedStateHandle: SavedStateHandle) : ViewModel() {
    val firstName = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<String>("firstName", "")

    // ...
    private val currentDidFetchUserData = savedStateHandle.getLiveData<Boolean>("didFetchUserData", false)
    val didFetchUserData: LiveData<Boolean> = currentDidFetchUserData

    private val currentHadErrorSavingData = MutableLiveData(false) // unlikely that this needs state restoration
    val hadErrorSavingData: LiveData<Boolean> = currentHadErrorSavingData

    private val currentHadErrorUpdatingData = MutableLiveData(false) // unlikely that this needs state restoration
    val hadErrorUpdatingData: LiveData<Boolean> = currentHadErrorUpdatingData // unlikely that this needs state restoration
}

@Stable
class UserProfileState(
    private val firstNameProvider: () -> String,
    private val didFetchUserDataProvider: () -> Boolean,
    private val hadErrorSavingDataProvider: () -> Boolean,
    private val hadErrorUpdatingDataProvider: () -> Boolean,
    private val onUpdateFirstName: (String) -> Unit,
) {
    val firstName: String get() = firstNameProvider()
    private val didFetchUserData: Boolean get() = didFetchUserDataProvider()
    val hadErrorSavingData: Boolean get() = hadErrorSavingDataProvider()
    val hadErrorUpdatingData: Boolean get() = hadErrorUpdatingDataProvider()

    fun updateFirstName(firstName: String) {
        onUpdateFirstName(firstName)
    }

    val isLoading: Boolean get() = !didFetchUserData
}


@Composable
fun NavigationGraph() {
    ...
    val userProfileViewModel = viewModel<UserProfileViewModel>()

    val firstName = userProfileViewModel.firstName.observeAsState("")
    val didFetchUserData = userProfileViewModel.didFetchUserData.observeAsState(false)
    val hadErrorSavingData = userProfileViewModel.hadErrorSavingData.observeAsState(false)
    val hadErrorUpdatingData = userProfileViewModel.hadErrorUpdatingData.observeAsState(false)
    
    val state = remember {
        UserProfileState(
            firstNameProvider = firstName::value::get,
            didFetchUserDataProvider = didFetchUserData::value::get,
            hadErrorSavingDataProvider = hadErrorSavingData::value::get,
            hadErrorUpdatingDataProvider = hadErrorUpdatingData::value::get,
            onUpdateFirstName = userProfileViewModel.firstName::setValue, // trick. viewModel::updateFirstName would be also ok
        )
    }
    UserProfileScreen(
        state = state,
    )
}

@Composable
fun UserProfileScreen(
    state: UserProfileState,
    modifier: Modifier = Modifier,
) {
    Box(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .then(modifier)
    ) {
        if (state.isLoading) {
            CircularProgressIndicator(modifier = Modifier
                .size(48.dp)
                .align(Alignment.Center))
        } else {
            TextField(
                value = state.firstName,
                onValueChange = state::updateFirstName,
            )
        }
    }
}
```

---

You definitely don't need to create your own `TextFieldValue`s especially in your composable, unless you need to also manipulate selection... but that is somewhat difficult to do and out of scope for this question, so I generally use `String` instead of `TextFieldValue`.

This is a bit of a tangent here, but it's worth noting what happens if the state is not hoisted in the ViewModel, as that's the example they use in the Codelabs.

If you ditch ViewModel entirely and move the state back into Composables, then you can ditch the `() -> String` and so on lazy accessors and follow https://developer.android.com/codelabs/jetpack-compose-advanced-state-side-effects#6 instead. Their solution provides lazy access as well:

```
class EditableUserInputState(private val hint: String, initialText: String) {
    var text by mutableStateOf(initialText)

    val isHint: Boolean
        get() = text == hint

    companion object {
        val Saver: Saver<EditableUserInputState, *> = listSaver(
            save = { listOf(it.hint, it.text) },
            restore = {
                EditableUserInputState(
                    hint = it[0],
                    initialText = it[1],
                )
            }
        )
    }
}
```

Except in their case, state is NOT hoisted to a ViewModel, so they track invalidation by specifying ***all arguments** of the state as remember keys.

```
@Composable
fun rememberEditableUserInputState(hint: String): EditableUserInputState =
    remember(hint) {
        EditableUserInputState(hint, hint)
    }
```

Overall, the answer is somewhere between #1 and #4, definitely not #2 and #3.

Dependencies require so:

```
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:2.6.1'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1'

implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime:1.4.3"
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.3'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to deal with a scenario, where your defaultValue might change over time (especially when navigating away from the screen an then coming back to it), you might stumble upon the fact, that `rememberSaveable(input = initialValue) {..}` will not apply a new initialValue when you navigate back to the screen. There is a ticket at Google, because this is not what one would expect: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/152014032

Google did also provide a workaround for this (using the key-Composable). Based on that I came up with the following helper function:

```
@Composable
public fun <T : Any> rememberSaveableWithVolatileInitialValue(
    initialValue: T
): MutableState<T> {
    return key(initialValue) {
        rememberSaveable {
            mutableStateOf(initialValue)
        }
    }
}
```

You can find a more detailed discussion of this helper function along with when and how to use it here:
[Jetpack Compose: Provide initial value for TextField](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74349840/jetpack-compose-provide-initial-value-for-textfield/74632382#74632382)

Comment: uh, that does look really interesting, I'll try it and mark this one as accepted if the solution is actually as tidy as that.

Answer (score -1):

The following is the best practice to define and update `TextField` state to prevent input issues. Please check [this link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/text/user-input#state-practices). Handling default or actual values can be implemented in `ViewModel` and send back the value to your UI/Jetpack Compose via a state.
Here's a simple example:

```
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        val vm: SignUpViewModel by viewModels()
        TestingAppTheme {
            
            Surface(
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                color = MaterialTheme.colors.background
            ) {
                SignUpScreen(userName = vm.username, 
              vm::updateUsername)
            }
          }
        }
     }
 }

 class SignUpViewModel(private val userRepository: UserRepository) : ViewModel() {

   var username by mutableStateOf("")
      private set

   fun updateUsername(input: String) {
       username = input
   }

   /**
   * the rest of code
   * ...
   */
 }

 @Composable
 fun SignUpScreen(userName: String, updateUserName: (name: String) -> Unit = {}) {

   /*
   * Here the rest of your composable code
   * ...
   * */
   OutlinedTextField(
      value = userName,
      onValueChange = { username -> 
      updateUserName.invoke(username) }
     /*...*/
   )
 }
```

If you're not planning to migrate from `LiveData` to `State` in your project, replace state with `LiveData`. Hope this solution helps.

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't really answer my question. How do you pass the ViewModel to the Composable? Also, couldn't you hoist the ViewModel out of the Composable.

Comment: Where to make an instance of ViewModel is up to you, it was just an example I provided. Please check my answer, I moved ViewModel out of SignupViewModel from the example. @4gus71n

Answer (score -1):

By implementing `implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.5.1"`, you can use a Composable function `viewModel` to get the viewModel in Composable. Like:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    // we only suggest getting the viewModel in `top-level` composable functions
    // this can reduce coupling between composable functions
    // and even improve the performance( ViewModel is not Stable for Compose Compiler)

    val vm: UserProfileViewModel = viewModel()
    // then you can use it
    val state by vm.state.observeAsState(initial = UserProfileViewModel.State.Loading)
    Detail(state)
}
```

In `Detail`, you can show different UI based on the State

```kotlin
// Now we can use the state in the Detail composable function
// It dose not need to know where the state comes from, not associated with the ViewModel
// if you want to change the value of the ViewModel, you can pass parameters to the composable function
// like : updateNewName: (String) -> Unit
// and pass it like : updateNewName = { newName -> vm.updateNewName(newName) }
@Composable
fun Detail(
    state: UserProfileViewModel.State,
) {
    when (state) {
        is UserProfileViewModel.State.UserDataFetched -> {
            val userData = (state as UserProfileViewModel.State.UserDataFetched)
            // UserDataFetchedUI(...)
        }
        UserProfileViewModel.State.ErrorFetchingData -> {
            // ErrorFetchingDataUI(...)
        }
        UserProfileViewModel.State.ErrorUpdatingData -> {
            // ErrorUpdatingDataUI(...)
        }
        UserProfileViewModel.State.Loading -> {
            // LoadingUI(...)
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to see some codes about this topic in a `real` project, you might refer to [here](https://github.com/FunnySaltyFish/FunnyTranslation/blob/68d07890d198e2b7150dcb41586fd104416892f0/translate/src/main/java/com/funny/translation/translate/ui/plugin/OnlinePlugin.kt#L4)

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't really answer my question. What happens if the user decides to dismiss the detail? How do I roll back to the previous value?

Comment: I think THIS IS your answer. In `Composable`, UI = f( State ), if you want to change UI, you just need to change the State. I don't know what does "How do I roll back to the previous value?" mean. If you want to navigate between Composables, you might use `navigation-compose`

Comment: In your example, if you want to change the value of TextField, you just need to change the vm::state, like `TextField(
            value = userData.firstName ,
            onValueChange = {
                updateUserName(it) // in viewModel, the method is: state.value = (state.value  as UserProfileViewModel.State.UserDataFetched).copy(firstName = it)            }
        )`